# Problem with Image Button visibility! Android

Tags: java, android, onclick, visibility, imagebutton

I have an Image button. I made it invisible. But the onClick event is not getting triggered which makes the button visible. The button should initially be visible for 5seconds, become invisible and then visible again if I click there.

```
private ImageButton nextbutton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.first );
        nextbutton = ((ImageButton)findViewById( R.id.NextButton ));
        nextbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        nextbutton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View v )
            {
                nextbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                startActivity( new Intent( FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class ) );
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to click an invisible button? Try using a visible button with a blank drawable, ie no background or src attributes.

when you click it, dynamically change the source attributes by inserting your desired drawable.

this will definitely make it clickable.

Comment: If you don't set a src or background I think your button is going to end up 0 by 0 size. I got something similar to this to work by using a png of the size I wanted that was nothing but transparent. Then I set it as my ImageButtons background.

Comment: manually set the size, wrap content won't work, but match_parent will, also setting your own dip values should too

Comment: I thought further about this and yes, use a png with alpha will doubly guarantee that this works.

Answer (score 0):

When you have made the ImageButton Invisible then how will you click an invisible ImageButton.

Comment: onClick or onTouch should make the button visible

Comment: if the button is not visible then you can not perform any onClick or onTouch event.?Can you elaborate why do you want to take such approach?

Comment: When you start the application, the buttons are visible for 5 seconds and then become invisible, so people will know there are buttons on the screen. For example If I have a MapActivity running, the button will be an obstruction. So I want to make it invisible. It should be visible again on touch so as to trigger another activity.

Comment: that's the wrong approach ... To achieve your goal you can use menu or you can use very small image for that which does not bother you on the screen.....