# Android Button Visiblity

Tags: java, android, timer, visibility, touch-event

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with Image Button visibility! Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959754/problem-with-image-button-visibility-android)

When you start the application, the buttons should be visible for 5 seconds and then become invisible, so people will know there are buttons on the screen. For example If I have a MapActivity running, the button will be an obstruction. So I want to make it invisible. It should be visible again on touching that area or around that button area so as to trigger another activity. I tried setting visibilitiy. nextbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) I can't make it visible onTouch() Please help me with the problem.

Comment: if I close my eyes for 5 seconds while opening your application, to relieve stress in anticipation of clicking buttons, how will I know what happened?

Comment: use mytracks application from google. It uses the same future!

Answer (score 2):

See your [original thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959754/problem-with-image-button-visibility-android) which has more than enough information for you to do what you want.

Comment: no it is not! I want some code!

Comment: Good luck with your bumming off StackOverflow goals for 2011!

Comment: Asking for people to write you code is **far** different then asking for help with a problem. If you want someone to write code for you, expect to pay for it.

Comment: well. Are there any tutorials u can suggest regarding this question?